# Setting titles on tabs in codebehind in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How would I go about setting the titles of all tabs in XamarinForms when the app loads in C# via the codebehind?

Currently, my app looks great on Android without the titles, with the titles it is just a congested mess due to the number of tabs.

On IOS, the app looks quite nice with all the tabs with the titles, as IOS inherently sends extra tabs to another page, "... More", rather than congesting the text.

What I want to do is, on IOS only, keep the titles on the tabs. In Android, I will keep it free of titles completely.

Here is the XAML, for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:engME"
            x:Class="engME.MainPage">
    <ContentPage Icon="name.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="settings.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="gear.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="inkpen.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="favorite.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="all.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="search.png">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Icon="random.png">
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnPlatform` for that:

```
<ContentPage Icon="name.png">
    <ContentPage.Title>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Name" />
            </OnPlatform.Platforms>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Title>
</ContentPage>
```

The default value will be an empty string so you just need to specify it for iOS. For more info look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have thought about that.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helped :)

Comment: Got it, please upvote the question if you can, so I’m not penalized. :)